# Grabbing file location via root

Tags: java, android, exception, text, filereader

Goal: to read contents of a file that is in my root directory. Eventually I want to be able to read a .conf file, but right now I am testing with a .txt file since it seems easier to begin with..

I am using the open source Shell file from an XDA video to navigate to my root directory. For reference, the file is located at: "/data/misc/joke.txt"

This is the code in my main method:

```
            String command[]={"su","-c","ls /data/misc"};
            Shell shell = new Shell();
            String output = shell.sendShellCommand(command);

            try {
                read(output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So basically all that is doing is granting SU permission, and then navigating to the /data/misc folder. Then in the Shell() class, I scan through each file and search for the text file I want. This might be redundant since I expect the text file to be "joke.txt" EVERYTIME. Anyways, I am having an issue with this block of code, the read() method:

```
    public void read(String out) throws Exception{

    File yourFile = new File("/data/misc", out);

    FileReader file = new FileReader(yourFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line;
    String text = "";
    line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        text += (line);
        line = reader.readLine();                       
    }

    setNewTextInTextView(text);
        }
```

It crashes at this line:

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader(yourFile);
```

Any tips?

Comment: what's crash log? null exception? no permission?

Comment: How are you executing `su`? Doing that via `Runtime#exec` will give the Process that executes that command root but not your app. `new FileReader` is not executed within that process so it has just your basic app permissions and will likely fail.

Comment: Im getting a "<s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading". Zapl, Im not really sure. When I run the app, it asks for SU root permission, so I assumed the application had root access. How would I be able to execute `new FileReader` as SU?

Comment: So I tried to open the file directly, and im getting a "can't execute: permission denied" error when using the command `String command[]={"su","-c","/data/misc/joke.txt"};`